# Typo3 Menu - problems with templating

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I know there are many tuts for creating a menu with typo3.. But it doesn't work for me, so I hope you can help me..

I do not know why my generated code will not show my sublevel-pages "Subpage 1" and "Subpage 2"..

My menu-structure is the following:

- Home
- Imprint

  - Subpage 1
- Test 1

  - Subpage 2

My Code in my template-file

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT
page.10.template = FILE
page.10.template.file = fileadmin/Template/index.html
temp.tmenu= HMENU 
temp.tmenu{

  1 = TMENU
  1.wrap = <ul class="menu-level1">|</ul>
  1{
    NO{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }
    ACT=1
    ACT{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level1-active">|</li>
    }
    CUR=1
    CUR{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level1-current-active">|</li>
    }
    IFSUB=1
    IFSUB{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level1-with-subpage">|</li>
    }
  }

  2 = TMENU
  2.wrap = <ul class="menu-level2">|</ul>
  2{
    NO{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }
    ACT=1
    ACT{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level2-active">|</li>
    }
    CUR=1
    CUR{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level2-current-active">|</li>
    }
    IFSUB=1
    IFSUB{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level2-with-subpage">|</li>
    }
  }

  3 = TMENU
  3.wrap = <ul class="menu-level3">|</ul>
  3{
    NO{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }
    ACT=1
    ACT{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level3-active">|</li>
    }
    CUR=1
    CUR{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level3-current-active">|</li>
    }
    IFSUB=1
    IFSUB{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-level3-with-subpage">|</li>
    }
  }
}

page.10.subparts {
  METANAV < temp.tmenu
}
```

And this is the generated output:

```
 <ul class="menu-level1">
<li class="menu-level1-current-active"><a href="index.php?id=2">Home</a></li>  
<li class="menu-level1-with-subpage"><a href="index.php?id=3">Imprint</a></li>
<li class="menu-level1-with-subpage"><a href="index.php?id=5">Test 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://typo3buddy.com/typoscript/menus/tmenu-left-menu/

```
expAll = 1
```

is your golden ticket